# Assigning the values of a list to the values of another list

Tags: python

I have

```
a = [price1, price2]
b = [[108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830], [3926, 4095, 426]]
```

How can I automate assigning `a[0]` equal to `b[0]`, and `a[1]` to `b[1]`?

Comment: How is what you want to do different from `a = b`?

Comment: What do you mean by `automate`? Your question seems not clear enough.

Comment: If `price1` and `price2` are variables whose values you want to change, you're coming at the problem from an odd direction.  Why not just use `b[0]` wherever you would have used `price1`?  If that's not what you're trying to do, then I'm afraid I don't understand.

Comment: It's just as a way to clarify what I'm working with. I'd like to be able to do `price1 = [108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830]` without having to manually say that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do something like this

```
b = [[108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830], [3926, 4095, 426]]
price1, price2 = b
```

or all on one line

```
price1, price2 = [[108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830], [3926, 4095, 426]]
```

Another possibility is to create a mutable object with an attribute to hold the price

```
>>> class Price(object):
...     def __init__(self, value=None):
...         self.value = value
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return "Price({})".format(self.value)
... 
>>> price1 = Price()
>>> price2 = Price()
>>> a = [price1, price2]
>>> b = [[108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830], [3926, 4095, 426]]
>>> for i,j in zip(a, b):
...     i.value = j
... 
>>> a
[Price([108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830]), Price([3926, 4095, 426])]
```

Comment: In your "all on one line", you don't even need the outer `[]`.  (i.e., you can unpack a tuple instead of a list).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to **associate** the strings in `a` with the values in `b`? IE the name `price1` to the first element in b? If so you want a dictionary:

```
 d = {}
 # i is the current position in a
 # key is the value at that position
 for i, key in enumerate(a):
     d[key] = b[i]
```

Do you just want to **overwrite** whats in b with a? Its as simple as

```
 a[0]=b[0]
```

or

```
 a = b
```

Comment: `dict(zip(a, b))` would be much more Pythonic. Assuming that's what he actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

Not real clear what you're looking for, how about this:

```
>>> price1 = 10000
>>> price2 = 22222
>>> a = [price1, price2]
>>> b = [[108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830], [3926, 4095, 426]]
>>>
>>> merged_ab = {a_item: b_item for a_item, b_item in zip(a,b)}
>>> merged_ab
{10000: [108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830], 22222: [3926, 4095, 426]}
>>>
```

Actually, `zip()` alone does this without the keying.

```
>>> zip(a,b)
[(10000, [108455, 106406, 103666, 101408, 98830]), (22222, [3926, 4095, 426])]
```

Comment: No need for a dictionary comprehension (which is Python3+). `dict(zip(a, b))` is all that's needed.

Comment: Lukas, yes dict(zip(a,b)) does the same thing, however, dictionary comprehensions *are* available in 2.7 as well.

Comment: you're right about dict comprehensions and 2.7 - how sweet is that? :)